# How to embed .swf file with jPlayer

Tags: jquery, swfobject, jplayer

I am trying to use jPlayer. When I see the website I can see media support many formats except `.swf`. But I want to embed the .swf file and I am targeting browsers with flash installed. If anybody came across the same issue please let me know how to embed .swf file with jPlayer. I have tried `SwfObject`. But I cannot find api for pause and stop and repeat. Please help me on this.

Comment: i'm not sure jPlayer is the correct library to solve your problem.. ".swf" files is not one of its supported media types.

Answer (score 0):

That's because jPlayer advertises itself like this: "The jQuery **HTML5** Audio / Video Library".
It has a support of Flash but only as a fallback. This means, that the browsers not supporting any media type provided by you or not supporting HTML5 audio/video tags will get the Flash fallback part of it.
Read the [**developer guide**](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/) about the [**files**](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-files) carefully and watch for this one:

```
$("#jpId").jPlayer( {
    swfPath: "/scripts/jPlayer"
});
```

You need to download the proper skin (the one you like) and it comes with it.

Comment: Thanks for info. Could you please also include code for passing .swf file as media.

Comment: i would redirect you to 2 links instead since I'm not really into Flash and embedding Flash:
http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/qt/embedswfwebpage.htm
&
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/object-tag-syntax-flash-professional.html
Read these ones.